# Trying to create a batch file to copy the 5th string from txt file and create txt file with string as filename

Tags: batch-file

My goal is to write a batch file to copy the 5th string inside of a text file and then create a file with that string as the file name.

Here is what I have so far, but it just creates a `new.txt` file with the string inside.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set "source=C:\Users\Sinis\Desktop\newtest\*.txt"
set "target=C:\Users\Sinis\Desktop\newtest\"%%b.txt" 
pushd "%source%"
set name =%%a
(
  for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /i /l /c:"Name" "*.txt"') do (
    echo(%%b
  )
) > "%target%"
popd
```

Comment: Please clarify. You say "fifth string", but use `tokens=1,*` - that doesn't match at all (besides some logical flaws in your code). Best show us a text file and tell us which string exactly you're after.

Comment: I managed to use your code above but with part of mine and it worked.  `for %%I in ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\newtest\*.txt") do for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%J in ('findstr /i /l /c:"Name" "*.txt"') do >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\newtest\%%K.txt" echo(%%K`   Thanks for your help it is much appreciated!

Comment: But how would I do this recursively?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example for you, with the additional request of recursion:

```bat
@Set "source=%UserProfile%\Desktop\newtest"
@PushD "%source%" 2>NUL || Exit /B
@For /F "Tokens=1,2*Delims=:" %%G In (
    'FindStr /IRS "\<Name\>" "%source%\*.txt" 2^>NUL'
) Do @For /F Tokens^=5EOL^= %%J In ("%%I") Do @Break>"%%~J.txt" 2>NUL
@PopD
```

Please note that this assumes that your lines containing the case insensitive word `Name` are space delimited, *for determining the fifth string*. Also any fifth string on any matched line should also not contain any character(s) which are invalid for filenames.

Your example in the comments has however confused me because it is using the entire line as the filename as well as writing that line to the file. If you want to write the fifth string to the filename and file, you could try replacing `@Break>"%%~J.txt" 2>NUL` with `@(Echo(%%J)>"%%~J.txt"`